# Mock a class whose methods are invoked in the test case

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

So I have a class I wrote some test cases for. This class has these two methods:

```
- (void)showNextNewsItem {
    self.xmlUrl = self.nextNewsUrl;
    [self loadWebViewContent];
}

- (void)showPreviousNewsItem {
    self.xmlUrl = self.previousNewsUrl;
    [self loadWebViewContent];
}
```

Could be refactored and this is quite primitive, but nevertheless I just want to make sure next loads next and previous loads previous. So I use OCMock to instantiate a `OCMockObject` for my SUT class like this:

```
- (void)testShowNextOrPreviousItemShouldReloadWebView {

    id mockSut = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[NewsItemDetailsViewController class]];

    [[[mockSut expect] andReturn:@"http://www.someurl.com"] nextNewsUrl];
    [[mockSut expect] loadWebViewContent];

    [[[mockSut expect] andReturn:@"http://www.someurl.com"] previousNewsUrl];
    [[mockSut expect] loadWebViewContent];

    [mockSut showNextNewsItem];
    [mockSut showPreviousNewsItem];

    [mockSut verify];
}
```

The problem lies in the two lines actually calling the methods that do something to be verified. OCMock now tells me, that invoking `showNextNewsItem` and `showPreviousNewsItem` are not expected. Of course, it's not expected because I am in the test and I only expect certain things to happen in the production code itself.

Which part of the mocking concept didn't I understand properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally confusing to mock the class under test, but if you want to do that, you need a "partial mock", so that you can call methods without stubbing them and have them execute the normal methods.

This appears to be supported in OCMock according to the [docs](http://ocmock.org/).

Comment: Thank you - that is correct. But unfortunately, iOS projects tend to accumulate "behavior-driven" methods instead of functions with a clear return value. This way I can only test the correct invocation of method calls rather than a result I expect. Maybe I should think about refactoring this. ;-)

Comment: Your own answer seems to suggest that you figured out how to do this with a partial mock.  Sorry if it wasn't clear, but I was trying to point you to exactly that, though I was also saying that it would be better to not mock the class you're testing.  Refactoring when you find the need for this is almost always a good idea.

Comment: That's right. The idea came to my mind probably at the same time you posted this. I'm gonna mark your answer as correct though - I just didn't want to post the whole code in a comment (which isn't even possible). Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks.  It all makes sense now.  I would have included code here except I'm really not an Objective-C programmer.  Good that you figured it out and put your code in an answer.  Have an upvote for that...

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. Using a partialMock on the object does exactly what I want. This way, calls I explicitly define are mocked and I call the methods that are under test on the "not-mocked" object.

```
- (void)testShowNextOrPreviousItemShouldReloadWebView {

    NewsItemDetailsViewController *sut = [[NewsItemDetailsViewController alloc] init];

    id mockSut = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:sut];

    [[[mockSut expect] andReturn:@"http://www.someurl.com"] nextNewsUrl];
    [[mockSut expect] loadWebViewContent];

    [[[mockSut expect] andReturn:@"http://www.someurl.com"] previousNewsUrl];
    [[mockSut expect] loadWebViewContent];

    [sut showNextNewsItem];
    [sut showPreviousNewsItem];

    [mockSut verify];
}
```